# Tkinter update values from other class

Tags: python, tkinter, config, python-multithreading

I've got a tkinter window that have 3 features: background color,foreground color, and a text label. These features is in a text config file (properties.conf) in my home folder. I want to update window features when the config file changed. I watch the changes in config file with pyinotify and I want to update window when it changes. This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
from Tkinter import *
import os
import ConfigParser
import pyinotify

class WatchFile(threading.Thread):
      def run(self):
          def onChange(ev):
              Gui().updateGUI()
              print 2
          wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
          wm.add_watch('/home/mnrl/window_configs', pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE, onChange)
          notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)
          notifier.loop()

class ConfigParse():
      def __init__(self):
          self.confDir =  os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'), 'window_configs/')
          self.confFile = os.path.join(self.confDir + "properties.conf")
          self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

          if os.path.isfile(self.confFile):
             self.config.read(self.confFile)
          else:
              if not os.path.exists(self.confDir):
                  os.makedirs(self.confDir)
              self.config.add_section('bolum1')
              self.config.set('section1', 'setting1', 'green')
              self.config.set('section1', 'setting2', 'red')
              self.config.set('section1', 'setting3', 'sample text')

              with open(self.confFile, 'wb') as self.confFile:
                    self.config.write(self.confFile)


class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.lbl = Label(self.root, text=ConfigParse().config.get('section1', 'setting3'), fg=ConfigParse().config.get('section1', 'setting1'),  bg=ConfigParse().config.get('section1', 'setting2'))
        self.lbl.pack()

    def updateGUI(self):
        self.lbl["text"] = ConfigParse().config.get('bolum1', 'ayar3')
        self.lbl["fg"] = ConfigParse().config.get('bolum1', 'ayar1')
        self.lbl["bg"] = ConfigParse().config.get('bolum1', 'ayar2')
        self.root.update()



WatchFile().start()
Gui().root.mainloop()
```

But whenever properties.conf file changes a new window more appears near the old tkinter window. So tkinter window not updates, new windows open. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `WatchFile.run()` you're doing this:

```
      def onChange(ev):
          Gui().updateGUI()
```

This does something different than what you're expecting. It creates a *new* `GUI` instance, and then immediately calls the `updateGUI()` method on it. Hence the two windows.

What you need to do instead, is something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

gui = None

class WatchFile(threading.Thread):
      def run(self):
          def onChange(ev):
              gui.updateGUI()

[...]

WatchFile().start()
gui = Gui()
gui.root.mainloop()
```

Here, a variable `gui` is created, and has an instance of your `GUI` class assigned to it. Later, the `updateGUI()` method is called on the same instance.

This problem is more or less repeated with your usage of your `ConfigParser` class, for example:

```
self.lbl["text"] = ConfigParse().config.get('bolum1', 'ayar3')
```

In this case, it 'works' because your ConfigParse() class can be executed twice without side-effects (such as opening windows), but it's not very efficient. You're reading the same file multiple times.
What would be better, is to just use a function (a class with only a `__init__` defined is effectively the same), run this once, and return a `dict`.

Comment: You don't need the `global gui` statement in `onChange`, since you're not reassigning `gui` from that function. It's always allowed to read global variables, you don't need a special declaration for it.

Comment: @Blckknght You're right, thank you for correcting that. Not sure what I was thinking.